# Exception safe server

Tags: c++, exception, server

I'm building a c++ server library, where the user of the library will implement responses to the clients. If the program encounter any runtime error in the response implementation, the server should not exit, it should just close thread/connection.

I've found two ways to doing this.

1. Use threads and use __try __except in order to catch the exceptions, for example access violation - close the thread.
2. Start a new process for each connection. Response time to the clients will be longer if not reloading the processes, and will use more RAM.

I'm mainly interested in the first alternative, but it's not recommended in any forums or papers that I've read.
The point is to make the server stable and never terminating.

What option should I use?

Comment: Access violations are just a possible result of undefined behavior on certain platforms. Out of bounds memory access is undefined behavior and there is no portable mechanism to recover from them. The only defense is prevention. You will need to specify your exact platform and implementation as you will need to use non-standard extensions if you want to recover from an access violation. The best option, in my opinion, is defensive programming techniques and exception safe code.

Comment: The library is cross-platform, Windows and Linux. x86 and x64.

Comment: _The point is to make the server stable and never terminating._ chose option 2

Comment: Alterative 2 is my choice if you want the most bulletproof solution. 
In my opinion there is no way to recover safely from access violation.
The root cause could be corruption of vital data. (Example: heap corruption).

Comment: It really depends what kind of "access violation" you're talking about.  If it's a coding error that results in a segmentation fault - as others have said, option 2 is the only way to be resilient against that.  If what you really meant is, for example, the client requested access to a resource they don't have permission to access - then exception handling and option 1 would be fine for that.

Answer (score 1):

> the user of the library will implement responses to the clients. If the program encounter any runtime error in the response implementation

If you do not control 100% of the code being executed, going multi-process is the *only* way to make this stable.

Catching any "crash" SEH exceptions is a brittle business. The code may have bugs that don't cause any exceptions whatsoever, but just overwrite memory and you get some wrong behavior later on.

You could still catch these exceptions, but once you catch one, you should terminate the process, since you can't know what else has been messed up in the process' state. (And a better way might actually be to not catch them and just let the process terminate, giving you the chance to collect a crash dump.)